# can't set a bind mount in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, fastapi

I tried setting a bind mount in my fastapi server service in docker compose

```
server:
    container_name: server
    image: mydockerimg
    command: ["python3.8", "-m", "uvicorn", "main:app", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--ssl-keyfile=./key.pem",  "--ssl-certfile=./cert.pem"]
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - mydata:/app/my_data/
```

I use [mkcert](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert) for my local certificates (for development) and is used in the command of the server service above. But when I run `docker compose up` I get this error

```
server  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 139, in create_ssl_context
server  |     ctx.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile, get_password)
server  | FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

This doesn't happen when I don't set a bind mount, the services starts and works fine in that case, so how does the certificates affect the bind mount, and the server??

Comment: Where physically is the certificate; is it build into the image, on the host system, or both?  If you `docker-compose run server ls`, is it there?  The bind mount hides _everything_ that's in the image under `/app`, which is probably your entire application, and I'd suggest deleting it could be a good practice.  (You shouldn't need `command:` or `working_dir:` to override the image settings in normal use either.)

Comment: Okay I think I know the issue now. The certificate is not physically installed in my host system just the image. So when I copy the root directory of my app into the image. The certificates are no where to be found. I want to try installing the certificates locally into the host system @DavidMaze

Comment: And everything works now that I installed the certificates on host system.@DavidMaze

Comment: A better fix is probably to delete the bind mount that's hiding the image content; or it might be easier to use a virtual environment without Docker for day-to-day development.

Comment: yea I would consider setting up a virtual environment without docker, thanks @DavidMaze

Answer (score 0):

If certs are located at `/app/my_data` within the container, then change the command options to point to the appropriate location: `"--ssl-keyfile=/app/my_data/key.pem",  "--ssl-certfile=/app/my_data/cert.pem"`

Comment: The issue was due to the fact that the certificates where installed on the image alone but not on the host system. So when I bind the root of the app on the host system(not containing the certificates) It kind of replaces the root directory of the built image(containing the certificates) so when `command` runs it doesn't find the certificates and throws an error. Installing the certificates locally in the host system fixes the issue.